# Bootstrap popovers and tooltips are not working

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make popovers work (as I've learned they depend on tooltips, so I put the tooltip in the same project, too). I have tried: bootrstrap.bundle.min.js alone, popper.min.js and bootstrap.js together as in the example. Nothing works. Please help.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        
            <!--<script src="/static/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>-->
            <script src="/static/popper.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/static/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script>
              $(function () {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
              })
            </script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
          </head>
        
          <body>
            <div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover"
                data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
                Popover on bottom
              </button>
        
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                title="Tooltip on bottom">
                Tooltip on bottom
              </button>
            </div>
          </body>
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </html>
```

EDIT: Code updated with the commenter's suggestions. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Where do you initialize your tooltips?

Comment: I haven't, but even when I had, they don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add the `jquery` and `bootstrap` scripts.

Second, you need to initialize the `tooltip`s and `popover`s with

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

This is working example, please check.

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!--<script src="/static/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="/static/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover"
        data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
        Popover on bottom
      </button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>
    </div>
  </body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: How to make it without jquery. There are many similar answers with using jquery.

Comment: Where did you put the functions, @Mina? In another file I should refer in the code?

When I put them in the head in <script></script> they don't work.

Comment: @Swantewit, Yes, you can add in another file, or just inject in a `script` but make sure that executed after the `bootstrap` and `jquery` script.

Comment: Ok, when I initialized the functions in the endscripts, they finally worked. Thank you :)